# Understanding and testing [self._class_._module_]._file_

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When reading a python-based software, I feel confused about a line of python code: `path = sys.modules[self.__class__.__module__].__file__`.

I can guess it was trying to return the file name in class file, but I'm not very clear about the exact usage of this.  I saved the related code segment into a file named `test.py` and I'm trying to test it by `python test.py`, but it does not print anything. How can I test this kind of file?

```
import os
import sys

class testloadfile:
  def __init__(self, test_path=None):
     if test_path is None:
        path = sys.modules[self.__class__.__module__].__file__
        # print path
        path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, os.pardir))
        # print path
        path = os.path.join(path, "test.r")
        print(path)
        test_path = path

    print("r file loaded")
```

Comment: Offhand, I do not see here "any sort of `main` routine" that a *command-line(!)* execution of `python` would be expected to pick-up on. Here, you define "a class," and you define a constructor for that class, *and* it seems that you've also tossed-in a `print` statement, but I don't see anything here that tells `python` what is supposed to be done when this `.py` file is executed from the command line. Therefore, I'm not surprised that it does nothing. **:-)** "Go thee now, and take a look," at some existing Python *(library)* code. Notice what they do, and do thee likewise.

Comment: That is really bizarre... It seems like `sys.modules[self.__class__.__module__].__file__` should just give you `__file__`...

Comment: What is the proper indentation level of the final `print`? Is it part of the `class` definition or part of the `__init__()` method—because as posted it's an indentation error.

Comment: @Mike: If the final `print()` is part of the `class` definition (and not part of the `__init__()` method), running the script will execute it when the class definition executes. Regardless, it looks like @mgilson is correct, it's just an convoluted way to get `__file__`.

Comment: Yup ... think I agree with ye ...

Comment: I found this answer after trying something similar. One thing to consider, `__file__` returns the  path of the module for this class. But, when inheriting from `testloadfile`, you might want the path of the child class. I think the code above is the only way to do that. It looks bizarre, but I think it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes in python have a `__module__` attribute which contains the name of the module in which the class was defined. Additionally, each module contains a [**`__file__`**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/import.html#__file__) attribute which has the full path to the `.py` file.

He is trying to get the file path for the file in which the class was defined but he's not going the best way with doing it, ideally you could just index [**`sys.modules`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) by using [**`__name__`**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/import.html#__name__):

```
path = sys.modules[__name__].__file__
```

instead of going through the class (i.e `self.__class__.__module__ == __name__`). Do note here that `if __name__ == "__main__"` this will fail because the [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/__main__.html#module-__main__) module does not have a `__file__` attribute defined. You'll need to safeguard against it:

```
path = sys.modules[__name__].__file__ if __name__ == "__main__" else __file__
```

where `if __name__ == "__main__"` then `__file__` will contain the path of the file being executed.

Next, add the usual clause in your script in order for it to initialize the object if the script is running as `__main__`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    testloadfile()  # initialize
```

Now, if you call it as the `__main__` script with:

```
python -m test.py
```

or if you `import` it, it will pickup the `__file__` attribute, print it and then print the file name.

**P.s**: Fix the indentation in your final `print`.